# How do I databind a dynamic In XAML UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public dynamic MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now I personally know MyProperty has a property Bass with a property called DisplayName, but in my unique situation I don't know the `MyProperty`s type at runtime.

How do I bind to this dynamic type in xaml? using `x:Bind` or `Binding`

I tried to do this:

`Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty.Base.DisplayName, Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"`

But I get the xaml error:

`Error: BindingExpression path error: 'MyProperty' property not found on 'Models.MyClass'. BindingExpression: Path='MyProperty.Base.DisplayName' DataItem='Models.MyClass'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `dynamic'? Have you tried using a converter?

Comment: Can you provide an MVCE? There's no general problem with binding to dynamics and your code snippet  works fine. The error suggests that MyProperty can't be found rather than a problem with the dynamic generation.